# Laravel websocket real time chat with vue.js

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, websocket, vuejs2

Hi I am trying to build a laravel real time chat. I configured websockets and it seems to be connecting, but now I am trying to send a message and its working but to the other user the message is not displayed unless I refresh the page. I was following a tutorial in youtube did everything like in the tutorial and I dont know why I am receiving this errors. If you can have a look I would appreciate it.

Errors I am receiving

```
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/utf8.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
```

ChatsComponent.vue

```
  <template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8">
            <div class="card card-default">
                <div class="card-header">Messages</div>
                <div class="card-body p-0">
                    <ul class="list-unstyled" style="height:300px; overflow-y:scroll">
                        <li class="p-2" v-for="(message,index) in messages" :key="index">
                            <strong>{{ message.user.name }}</strong>
                            {{ message.message }}
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <input
                    @keyup.enter="sendMessage"
                    v-model="newMessage"
                    type="text" 
                    name="message" 
                    placeholder="Enter your message..."
                    class="form-control">
            </div>
             <span class="text-muted">User is typing...</span>
        </div>

        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="card card-default">
                <div class="card-header">Active Users</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="py-2">Harish</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {

        props:['user'],

        data(){
            return {
                messages:[],
                newMessage:'',
            }
        },

        created(){
           this.fetchMessages();

           Echo.join('chat')
            .listen('MessageSent', (event) => {
                this.messages.push(event.message);
            });

        },

        methods:{
            fetchMessages(){
              axios.get('messages').then(response =>{
                this.messages = response.data
                })                
            },

            sendMessage(){
                this.messages.push({
                    user:this.user,
                    message:this.newMessage
                });
                
                axios.post('messages', {message: this.newMessage});

                this.newMessage='';
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Message Model

```
class Message extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['message'];
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

And I added this to User model

```
public function messages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Message::class);
    }
```

ChatsController

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Message;
use App\Events\MessageSent;

class ChatsController extends Controller
{
    public function _construct(){
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    
    public function index()
    {
        return view('chats');
    }

    public function fetchMessages()
    {
        return Message::with('user')->get();
    }

    public function sendMessages(Request $request)
    {
       $message = auth()->user()->messages()->create([
            'message' => $request->message
        ]);

        broadcast(new MessageSent($message->load('user')))->toOthers();
        
        return ['status' =>'success'];
    }
}
```

MessageEvent event

```
App\Message; use App\User;

class MessageSent implements ShouldBroadcast

{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
    public $message;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Message $message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PresenceChannel('chat');
    }
}
```

Routes

```
Route::get('/chats','ChatsController@index')->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/messages','ChatsController@fetchMessages');
Route::post('/messages','ChatsController@sendMessages');
Broadcast::channel('chat', function ($user) {
   return $user;
});
```

Chat view

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <chats :user="{{ auth()->user()}}"></chats>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: don't put all code debug this and past only those code which is problem

Comment: how can I debug

Comment: where u r getting this error .?

Comment: I guess in the echo because other user does not receive teh message unless i refresh the page

Comment: Can't tell you exatly what is wrong but seems to me that there is something wrong with the evnet. Since it is writing to the databse when you make the request and the other users can get the data when they refresh. I would try debugging the websocket connection and see what is beeing sent back and forth.

Side note the error is not related to websocket the error just means that the file `/js/utf8.js.map` does not exist on your server. [Read about source maps here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Use_a_source_map)